# 20.04 LTS: Packages Not Fully Installed or Removed

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04

My searching has not netted me a solution to this problem and the errors I'm seeing aren't helping in applying the fixes that others have suggested...

Running 20.04LTS Server, having upgraded (do-release-ugrade) from 18.04. Everything seems to be working as expected with the exception of:

```
assetto@racetrack:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-64-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 13.9 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 132405 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-5.4.0-64-generic (5.4.0-64.72~18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.4.0-64-generic (--remove):
 cannot remove '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-64-generic/include/config/snd/soc/wm8711.h': Bad message
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.4.0-64-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried all the standard apt, dpkg, apt-get commands, including trying to force a reinstall of the named pkgs, but eveyrthing fails in this same way.

Any help would be appreciated.